# How to search for Debian packages by tags?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

At Debian's [Packages](http://packages.debian.org/) page, one can search amongst the software available on Debian. In the package descriptions, they are categorized by tags, [described here](http://packages.debian.org/about/debtags). For instance, the package `[xterm][3]` has the following tags:

> Tags: Implemented in: C, User Interface: X Window System, Role: Program, Scope: scope::utility, uitoolkit::athena, Purpose: Need an extra tag, X Window System: Application, Terminal Emulator

Is there a way to search or browser for packages according to these tags?

Answer (score 6):

there are a number of front-ends to access these tags, e.g.

```
debtags search "uitoolkit::athena && scope::utility"
```

you might want to have a look at the [Debian documentation on tags](https://wiki.debian.org/Debtags)